# Need some help and tips with custom character sheet

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm using c# as main programming language. Linked EF to WPF app.
Things I want: Possibility to save\load character or/and player info and use it.
Things I have:

Local DB with Players and Characters Table.
Players have:

```
P_ID 
P_Name
```

Characters have

```
id (int)
name (nvarchar50)
pid (int)
STR (int)
DEX (int)
INT (int)
```

I've found that entity framework is great solution (at least I think so) for what I want.

Currently I have Character and player classes that looks like this:

```
public class Character
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public int STR { get; set; }
    public int DEX { get; set; }
    public int INT { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("pid")]
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int P_ID { get; set; }
    public string P_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

MyDBcontext class:

```
public class MyDBcontext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBcontext() : base("Datasex_0._1.Properties.Settings.StraightCon")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Main window that looks like this (yet)]

and MainWindow.xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyDBcontext mdb;

    List<Player> playerlist = new List<Player>();
    List<Character> charlist = new List<Character>();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mdb = new MyDBcontext();
        mdb.Players.Load();
        mdb.Characters.Load();

        var charlist = mdb.Characters.ToList();
        var playerlist = mdb.Players.ToList();

        PlayerBox.ItemsSource = mdb.Players.ToList();

        CharacterData.ItemsSource = charlist;

        this.Closing += MainWindow1_Closed;
    }

    private void MainWindow1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdb.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What I need:

I've linked for testing purpose datagrid to a list. Problems with this: datagrid shows Players like this:

[image: Launched app]

I don't need Players to be in charlist.
Why do I need lists - somewhere here I found that I could use lists for combobox comparison.

I need to show all players in playersbox (1st combobox) - I did it.
Then I need to show characters that bound to player P_ID via pid in Characterbox combobox.

After this I need to show in textboxes (which I will add after I complete character tasks) character stats (str dex and int).
Then I need feature to add custom player to Database (I know how to do it because tested it in winforms app).

Then I need to add custom character based on selected player in playerbox (I don't know how to do it).

finally I need to have ability to change character info (name, str, dex and etc.) in UI.

Thanks for help and tips and sorry for my bad English.

edited:
added something that don't works as I thought:

```
private string[] getcharbyid (int pid)
        {
            return charlist.Where(Line => Line.pid == pid).Select(l => l.name).ToArray();
        }
```

and

private void PlayerBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
if (CharacterBox != null) CharacterBox.Items.Clear();

```
    int xid = charlist[PlayerBox.SelectedIndex].pid;

    indextest.Content = xid;

    foreach (string name in getcharbyid(xid))
    {
        this.CharacterBox.Items.Add(name);
    }
```

when application launches it says: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

compared id and index like this:

```
PlayerData.ItemsSource = mdb.Players.ToList();
int xid = PlayerBox.SelectedIndex;

indextest.Content = xid;
```

seems like id and index (or I'm doing something wrong) is same.
Attempts to change foreach was failed.

changed some code to add characters to characterbox:

```
    int xid;
    Int32.TryParse(PlayerBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), out xid);
    indextest.Content = xid;
    CharacterBox.Items.Add (from Character in charlist where Character.pid == xid select Character);
    CharacterBox.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
    CharacterBox.SelectedValuePath = "id";
```

it seems like characters added to combobox but I don't see their names and values:

empty character combobox?
[image: "empty character combobox?"]

Comment: if i'm doin something wrong and there is much simple way to do it (like throw away EF and stat dealing with sql commands) will be glad to see your thoughts and advices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved by using LINQ query. My thoughts was right - there was simple solution!